# Downloading xlrd utilities and collection package for PyQGIS

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, excel

```py
import xlrd
from xlutils.copy import copy
from collections import defaultdict
```

Error shown as:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'xlutils'

Tried to download in Plugin--->Manage and Install packages and there is no packages for Excel.

Answer (score 5):

`xlutils` is  a python package, not a QGIS plugin. You should install it using `pip install xlutils` in OSGEO Shell.

Comment: I have download OSGEO4.exe and there is no python in it

Comment: getting error as ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement xlutils==1.4.1 (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for xlutiles    Please help me on this

Comment: @Kadir, I though you are working now on your PhD Thesis, so no time for GIS SE, do not you? 

Comment: See im new to qgis .. if u can help me, i can learn